Directus new sdk - refresh token missing
I am using the new SDK to authenticate against directus within a svelte app.
I am trying to use the composable client.
For both login and logout, I set up the directus instance within a help function, directus.js
export function getDirectusInstance(fetch) {
  const options = fetch ? { globals: { fetch } } : {};
  const directus = createDirectus(import.meta.env.VITE_DIRECTUS_URL ).with(authentication()).with(rest());
    return directus;
}

Then login code is
const directus = getDirectusInstance();
await directus.login(email, password)
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("object returned from login is " + JSON.stringify(data))
             etc
             etc

And the console log shows

object returned from login is
{"expires":900000,"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cC.....PiisfX4","expires_at":1725011151976}

The docs say that this should include a refresh token when using the default mode param of 'json'. But I do not have a refresh token.
For logout,
 const directus = getDirectusInstance();
 await directus.logout()
            .then(() => {
                // do things            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Logout error " + JSON.stringify(error));
            });

And in the browser log

Logout error {"errors":[{"message":"Invalid payload. The refresh token
is required in either the payload or
cookie.","extensions":{"code":"INVALID_PAYLOAD","reason":"The refresh
token is required in either the payload or cookie"}}],"response":{}}

Again the docs say that for the composable client, no params are required. But the logout is failing.
There is a cookie which is an array of three of hex strings but I can't find docs on these.
Finally, just to add, when I was using the old style SDK, logout did work but I did get a message in the browser log complaining that the refresh token was missing but nevertheless the user was logged out.
So, in summary, why is logout() not working when the docs say it should. And why is there no refresh token in the return from login(em, pw).
Many thanks.
